# IRIX 6.x で使用されていたxファイルを実行したい

Tags: linux, unix

訳あって古い（1998年作成）プログラムを実行したいと思っています．

X線回折に関するとあるプログラムなのですが，IRIX6.2,6.3でコンパイルされたプログラムのようです．拡張子が ".x"のファイルを使用しており，これはIRIX6.xで実行可能なファイルだと書かれています．

Linux(CentOS6.6: 64bit, Ubuntu14.10: 64bit)で実行を試みましたが，エラーが出てしまいました．

> cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

xファイルはMicrosoftのdirectx9.0以前がサポートしているらしいので，directx9.0cをインストールしようとしたのですが，.NET Frameworkのインストールがうまくいかず，保留中です．
（※進展があれば追記します）

そもそも素人には，directxを入れれば解決する問題なのか，それともなにか他の問題なのか判断がつきません．IRIXでコンパイルされたプログラムを現在のLinuxで使用することはできないのでしょうか？

プログラムは以下のリンクから入手可能です．ダウンロードおよび実行でコンピュータに問題が生じたということは今のところありませんが，あくまで自己責任でダウンロードをお願いします．
http://wayback.archive.org/web/20030212203113/http://tui.foodsci.purdue.edu/CPRL/

Comment: DirectXも.NETも関係ありません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ソースコード見たところLinuxでもメイク出来そうですね。

前提条件
make と cc が必要です

```
$ which cc
/usr/bin/cc
$ which make
/usr/bin/make
```

ソースのダウンロートと展開

```
$ wget http://wayback.archive.org/web/20030212203113/http://tui.foodsci.purdue.edu/CPRL/cprl_1_0.tar.gz
--2015-06-23 12:22:40--  http://wayback.archive.org/web/20030212203113/http://tui.foodsci.purdue.edu/CPRL/cprl_1_0.tar.gz
wayback.archive.org をDNSに問いあわせています... 207.241.224.26, 207.241.224.26
wayback.archive.org|207.241.224.26|:80 に接続しています... 接続しました。
HTTP による接続要求を送信しました、応答を待っています... 302 Moved Temporarily
場所: /web/20010614203444/http://tui.foodsci.purdue.edu/CPRL/cprl_1_0.tar.gz [続く]
--2015-06-23 12:22:40--  http://wayback.archive.org/web/20010614203444/http://tui.foodsci.purdue.edu/CPRL/cprl_1_0.tar.gz
wayback.archive.org|207.241.224.26|:80 に接続しています... 接続しました。
HTTP による接続要求を送信しました、応答を待っています... 200 OK
長さ: 102600 (100K) [application/x-tar]
`cprl_1_0.tar.gz' に保存中

100%[==========================================================>] 102,600      221K/s 時間 0.5s

2015-06-23 12:22:41 (221 KB/s) - `cprl_1_0.tar.gz' へ保存完了 [102600/102600]

$ tar xfvz cprl_1_0.tar.gz
cprl_1_0/
cprl_1_0/cprl.c
cprl_1_0/cprl.cfg
cprl_1_0/cprl.data
cprl_1_0/cprl.pl
cprl_1_0/cprl.x
cprl_1_0/cprl_manual.ps
cprl_1_0/example_1.inp
cprl_1_0/example_1.out
cprl_1_0/example_1.ps
cprl_1_0/makefile
```

ソースをビルド

```
$ cd cprl_1_0
$ make
cc    -c -o cprl.o cprl.c
cprl.c: In function ‘main’:
cprl.c:179: 警告: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
cprl.c:238: 警告: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
cprl.c:350: 警告: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
cprl.c:516: 警告: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
cc -o cprl.x cprl.o  -lm
```

実行

```
$ ./cprl.x example_1.inp test.out example_1.ps
$ ll test.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 admin admin   3270  6月 23 12:23 2015 test.out
$ cat test.out
CPRL version 1.0 June 1998

triclinic vs monoclinic

Resolution is 0.30 reciprocal angstroms.

Option 1: Plot two unit cells for comparison.

First unit cell parameters:
6.74 5.93 10.36 117.00 113.00 81.00
tau = 0.00 theta = 0.00

Reciprocal cell parameters:
0.16 0.19 0.12 64.40 68.70 88.54

Cylindrically projected recipriocal lattice points:

   h    k    l      rho        R         Z
   0    0    0    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
  -1    0    0    0.1612    0.1612    0.0000
   1    0    0    0.1612    0.1612    0.0000
   0   -1    0    0.1893    0.1893    0.0000
   0    1    0    0.1893    0.1893    0.0000
  -1    1    0    0.2455    0.2455    0.0000
   1   -1    0    0.2455    0.2455    0.0000
  -1   -1    0    0.2518    0.2518    0.0000
   1    1    0    0.2518    0.2518    0.0000
   0    0    1    0.1163    0.0648    0.0965
  -1    0    1    0.1609    0.1288    0.0965
   0   -1    1    0.1742    0.1450    0.0965
  -1   -1    1    0.2104    0.1870    0.0965
   1    0    1    0.2305    0.2093    0.0965
   0    1    1    0.2615    0.2430    0.0965
   1   -1    1    0.2615    0.2431    0.0965
  -1    1    1    0.2814    0.2644    0.0965
   0   -1    2    0.2278    0.1209    0.1931
  -1   -1    2    0.2284    0.1221    0.1931
  -1    0    2    0.2299    0.1248    0.1931
   0    0    2    0.2326    0.1297    0.1931

Second unit cell parameters:
7.88 8.20 10.36 90.00 90.00 96.50
tau = 0.0000 theta = 0.0000

Reciprocal cell parameters:
0.13 0.12 0.10 90.00 90.00 83.50

Cylindrically projected recipriocal lattice points:

   h    k    l      rho        R         Z
   0    0    0    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
   0   -1    0    0.1227    0.1227    0.0000
   0    1    0    0.1227    0.1227    0.0000
  -1    0    0    0.1277    0.1277    0.0000
   1    0    0    0.1277    0.1277    0.0000
  -1    1    0    0.1668    0.1668    0.0000
   1   -1    0    0.1668    0.1668    0.0000
  -1   -1    0    0.1869    0.1869    0.0000
   1    1    0    0.1869    0.1869    0.0000
   0   -2    0    0.2455    0.2455    0.0000
  -2    0    0    0.2554    0.2554    0.0000
   1   -2    0    0.2636    0.2636    0.0000
  -2    1    0    0.2706    0.2706    0.0000
  -1   -2    0    0.2893    0.2893    0.0000
  -2   -1    0    0.2957    0.2957    0.0000
   0    0    1    0.0965    0.0000    0.0965
   0   -1    1    0.1561    0.1227    0.0965
   0    1    1    0.1561    0.1227    0.0965
  -1    0    1    0.1601    0.1277    0.0965
   1    0    1    0.1601    0.1277    0.0965
  -1    1    1    0.1927    0.1668    0.0965
   1   -1    1    0.1927    0.1668    0.0965
  -1   -1    1    0.2103    0.1869    0.0965
   1    1    1    0.2103    0.1869    0.0965
   0   -2    1    0.2638    0.2455    0.0965
  -2    0    1    0.2731    0.2554    0.0965
   1   -2    1    0.2807    0.2636    0.0965
  -2    1    1    0.2873    0.2706    0.0965
   0    0    2    0.1931    0.0000    0.1931
   0   -1    2    0.2288    0.1227    0.1931
   0    1    2    0.2288    0.1227    0.1931
  -1    0    2    0.2315    0.1277    0.1931
   1    0    2    0.2315    0.1277    0.1931
  -1    1    2    0.2551    0.1668    0.1931
   1   -1    2    0.2551    0.1668    0.1931
  -1   -1    2    0.2687    0.1869    0.1931
   1    1    2    0.2687    0.1869    0.1931

EOF: Thank you.
```

実行結果が正しいかはわたしには分かりませんのであしからず。

Comment: 一度makeは試していたのですが，なにかエラーになっていたらしく，もう一度wgetしてから試したところ成功しました．ありがとうございます．

Answer (score 2):

リンク先のアーカイブにはソースコード(cprl.c)も含まれていますので、gcc などでコンパイルすれば良いのではないでしょうか。Warning が多数表示されますが、実行形式ファイルが生成されます。

```
$ gcc -O -o cprl cprl.c -lm
```

同梱されている入力データのサンプルを指定して実行したところ、それらしい結果のファイルが出力されます。

```
$ ./cprl example_1.inp output.dat output.ps
```

ただし、予想される出力結果(`example_1.out`)と `output.dat` の中身に違いがあります。

Comment: Mac(yosemite)のgccでも動きました。`open output.ps`としてポストスクリプトも閲覧可能でした。

Comment: makeしてみました(CentOS7)。確かに結果がexample_1.outとは違いますね。ただ、これは元のinputとoutputのサンプルにバージョン差異があるように感じますが。質問者の方には表示される数値の意味が解るのでしょうからご自身で妥当性を検証していただくのがいいかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

前提知識として
IRIS は Silicon Graphics International 社製の MIPS プロセッサを使ったマシンです。
IRIX は IRIS 上で動く UNIX 系 (SysV ベース BSD 拡張あり) OS です。
提供打ち切りが 2006 年、サポート終了が 2013 年だったか？
2015 年現在 IRIS の新品マシンを入手するのは困難でしょう。

で・・・
動かしたいソフトのソースコードはあるのですか？あれば Linux に移植してください。
バイナリしかないのであれば考えられる手は
1. 中古 IRIS マシンを購入してください (IRIX がインストール済みであることを確認)
2. Linux/Windows 上で実行できる IRIX Simulator/Emulator を入手してください。
URI 書いていいのかよくわからないので検索してみてください。

異 CPU 異 OS だから IRIX 用バイナリが現在の Linux でそのまま動作することはありません。
DirectX/.NET Framework は無関係です。

Answer (score 1):

DirectXのサポートする[Xファイル](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb174837(v=vs.85).aspx)は

> X ファイルは、メッシュ、テクスチャー、アニメーション、およびユーザーによる定義が可能なオブジェクトの格納を可能にする、テンプレート駆動型フォーマットを提供します。

であり、質問の「X線回折」とは無関係です。

/* 以前SGI O2上でIRXI 6.xを使用していました。 */